# What's the best way to change my software mirror to a hardware one?

Tags: windows, raid-1

I currently have mirrored drives in Windows 10, and am planning to convert them to hardware RAID (using a PCI-e RAID card).

Please advise if the approach below is fine, or if anything else needs to be done:

- Break the mirror
- Shutdown the computer
- Install the RAID card and plug the drives into it
- Configure the RAID card
- Start into Windows

Comment: I am fairly sure you have to rebuild the Windows OS.  That is a lot of work for an OS that dies next year.